# Assembling $f(x)= -x^3 + 6x^2 +15x$ television sets

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> An efficiency study of the morning shift at a certain factory indicates that an 
>   average worker arriving on the job at 8:00 A.M. will have assembled $f(x)= -x^3 + 6x^2 +15x$ television sets $x$ hours later.

a) How many sets will such a worker have assembled by $10:00$ AM? [Hint At $10:00$ AM, $x=2$]

b) How many sets will such a worker assembled between $9:00$ and $10:00$ A.M?

Answer (score 3):

$$ f(x)= -x^3 + 6x^2 +15x$$

$$f(0)=0\tag{at 8 a.m}$$
$$f(1)=-1^3+6\cdot1^2+15\cdot1=20\tag{till 9 a.m}$$

$$f(2)=-2^3+6\cdot2^2+15\cdot2=46\tag{till 10 a.m}$$

So if you need to find set's assembled between $9 \text{ am }$ and  $10 \text{ am }$ you do

$$f(2)-f(1)$$

I hope you can take it from here!

Comment: I can be wrong but, if not, it is amazing that with your name you missed that. Cheers.

Comment: It's weird that the question is tagged algebra-precalculus while the title explicitly says calculus! So I think this solution is fine, if the author does not say the opposite.

Comment: @rubik: I have changed the title to reflect the fact that this is not actually a calculus problem. The error is the Original Poster's, not yours or Claude's or Integrator's.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Since time is continuous, I wonder if the result is not the integral of $f(x)$ over the period of time.

So, if I am right $$\int f(x)dx=-\frac{x^4}{4}+2 x^3+\frac{15 x^2}{2}$$ Apply the bounds.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: I could be possibly wrong too ! My problem is that I get a fractional number of TV sets ! Cheers :-)

Comment: If $f(x)$ were the *rate of work* you would be right, but here $f(x)$ is the total number of TV sets after $x$ hours. This is not actually a calculus problem, despite the initial title.

Comment: @RoryDaulton. You are perfectly right ! Thanks for pointing.